# Likelihood approximations for shared parameter problems

Tags: machine-learning, maximum-likelihood, references, inference, likelihood

In graphical models people tend to exploit conditional independence to factorize the likelihood and make the problem simpler. By simpler I mean that the dimension is reduced due to factorization. For example:

Consider 3 random variables $y1,y2$ and $y3$ and consider the graph structure
$$y1 \rightarrow y3 \leftarrow y2$$

In this case we can write the joint density
$$f(y1,y2,y3)=f(y1)f(y2)f(y3|y1,y2)$$
Such a factorization allows us to optimize the factors $\Big((f(y1);f(y2);f(y3|y1,y2)\Big)$ separately if we aim to find the MLE of the joint density.This factorization greatly reduces the dimensionality of the problem.

What if the factors, e.g. $f(y1)$ and $f(y3|y1,y2)$, have shared parameters. In this case we cannot maximize the joint likelihood through maximizing each factor separately. What are the approximations used in such cases ?
What are some key papers or key words used to handle such a task ?

Comment: Any joint distribution $f(y_1, \dots, y_n)$ is uniquely determined by its associated conditional distributions $f(y_1 | y_2, \dots, y_n), f(y_2 | y_1, y_3, \dots, y_n)$ etc., so if "factorizing" this way were really a way to greatly reduce the dimensionality of the joint problem, it would already always be done.

Answer (score 0):

Following your example, say we have $f(y1; \theta, \theta_1), f(y2; \theta_2),$ and $f(y_3|y1,y2; \theta, \theta_3)$, then
\begin{align*}
f(y_1,y_2,y_3; \theta, \theta_1, \theta_2, \theta_3) &= f(y_1; \theta, \theta_1)f(y_2; \theta_2)f(y_3|y1,y2; \theta, \theta_3)\\
\log f(y_1,y_2,y_3; \theta, \theta_1, \theta_2, \theta_3) &= \log f(y_1; \theta, \theta_1)+\log f(y_2; \theta_2) + \log f(y_3|y1,y2; \theta, \theta_3)
\end{align*}
So maximizing the joint likelihood with respect to $\theta$ is just maximizing $$\sum_i \{\log f(y_{1i}; \theta, \theta_1) + \log f(y_{3i}|y_{1i},y_{2i}; \theta, \theta_3)\}$$